# Getting an error in beanshell sampler while running on VM

Tags: jmeter

While running a Jmeter script locally on my machine I do not get any error but when I run the same script on a VM on which I installed the same java version I am getting the following error in beanshell sampler. can someone help me fix this :

at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_311]
2021-12-05 12:26:10,098 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import java.util.*; import java.time.*; import java.lang.*; import java.io.*;  t . . . '' : TargetError 2021-12-05 12:26:10,098 WARN o.a.j.p.j.s.BeanShellSampler: Exception executing script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of:` import java.util.*; import java.time.*; import java.lang.*; import java.io.*;  t . . . '' : TargetError

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't provide enough level of details in order to guess the failure reason.

You need to provide your full code to get support.

If the code contains sensitive data here are some debugging tips:

1. You can wrap your code into [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

   ```
   try {
       //your code here
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
       log.error("Beanshell failure", ex);
   }
   ```

   this way you will get more informative [stacktrace](https://stackify.com/java-stack-trace/) in [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file
2. Adding [`debug();` directive](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) to your script will help to get to the bottom of the problem
3. And last but not the least, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), the reasons are in:

   - Groovy is more compatible with Java
   - Groovy performance is much better
   - [Groovy SDK](https://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) provides more features on top of normal Java SDK so it's more powerful

   More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for spending time on this one. I have figured out the issue. I had an issue with my script which I have fixed now.